# Get comma separated values of checked items values of CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, checkedlistbox

I found this code to take values from CheckedListBox with commas. But there is no Selected and Value definition for CheckedListBox object. (there are just 4 basic inheritances :Equals(), GetHashCode(), GetType(), ToString())

[image: Selected and Value properties giving error.]

Which reference I need or how can I correct this error?

I put that image to show where it throws me error,  here is the code:

```
string values = "";
for (int i = 0; i < clSiparisTipi.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (clSiparisTipi.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        values += clSiparisTipi.Items[i].Value + ",";
    }
}
values = values.TrimEnd(',');
```

Edit: I also tried this code:

```
StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    items.Append(item).Append(",");
}

MessageBox.Show(items.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
```

But for example when I chose two items from the list, giving me such result: System.Data.DataRowView,System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: "Selected" not present, ok there must be a alternative "Checked". Try that

Comment: Of course I checked. there are just 4 basic inheritances:Equals(), GetHashCode(), GetType(), ToString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code (I guess I would mention about how do I populate items in my question)

```
StringBuilder items = new StringBuilder();
foreach (object checkedItem in clSiparisTipi.CheckedItems)
{
    DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)checkedItem;
    items.Append(dr["tanimId"]).Append(",");
}

MessageBox.Show(items.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
```

Comment: You could also just do `string items = string.Join(",",  clSiparisTipi.CheckedItems.Cast<DataRowView>().Select(x => x["tanimId"].ToString()));`

Answer (score 1):

CheckedListBox exposes a SelectedItems collection.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx

This in turn exposes a count and it's Item's are accessible via an index.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in clSiparisTipi.SelectedItems){
   sb.Append((String)item.Value)
     .Append(",");
}
// Remove trailing comma
sb.Remove(sb.Length-1,1);
string values = sb.ToString();
```

That should do the trick. Also be aware that concatenating strings is somewhat expensive. It's faster to use a StringBuilder whenever possible.

Comment: I think you need add checking of `sb.Length` before using  `sb.Remove`.

Comment: Again no definition.. Giving this error: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Once I done in this way..

```
var items = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Object ss in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
items.Append(string.Format("{0},",ss.ToString()));
```